# Reading data from multiple remote resources

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

Suppose I have many HttpURLConnection opened, and I'm trying to download data from that remote resources, by using many threads. I actually do this with a loop like this, provided one thread can have just one opened connection at a time. Because remote resources are slower than my connection in sending data, I have to use many threads to download more resources in the "same time":

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream())); // può lanciare IOEXC
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { // bloccante
    buffer.append(inputLine).append('\n');
    cicliLettura++;
}
```

I have some questions about this:

1. If data is not available, a single thread stops at the `while` line. Does it blocks all  threads (and if not, why?)
2. Does java automatically manage the many `in.readLine()` that could be called at the same time from many threads?

Comment: Pretty sure that a socket's input stream isn't thread-safe (answering your second question), much less InputStreamReader and BufferedReader. I'm not sure you gain anything from using many threads, besides.

Comment: Post you entire thread-related code.

Comment: i just have many connections like this, placed in different threads, that manage downloads the same way. One thread has just one opened connection. I have updated the question in the first part

Comment: sure, 1:1 relationship. Can throw IOException and Blocking

Answer (score 1):

> if data is not available, a single thread stops at the "while" line.
>   Does it blocks all threads (and if not, why?)

Of course not - that's, (mostly), what threads are for, to provide good I/O performance.  The underlying OS removes execution from the thread that has requested input that is not immediately available and makes that execution available to other threads that can make forward progress.

> Does java automatically manage the many in.readLine() that could be
>   called at the same time from many threads?

Assuming that each thread has its own 'in' instance, (and any other per-socket resource), there is not much managing to do.

Comment: it seems great, best expected scenario :) i'll try asap and mark the answer